# Android ToolBar Up button not launching Parent Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-toolbar

I have an app where I first display a Setting screen where user can save some details, I wanted to launch a Main Activity when user click on Up button in toolbar, but currently when Up button is clicked app just gets closed.

Here is my manifest

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.xyz.activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_welcome"
        android:launchMode="standard"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.xyz.activity.IntroActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.xyz.activity.SetLocationActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="com.xyz.activity.MainActivity">
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.xyz.activity.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

And

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

Any help

Comment: Is MainActivity in stack.? I meant have you started that activity?

Comment: have you set  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: I think you should provide more information about your onCreateOptionsMenu in SetLocationActivity and how to reach SetLocationActivity, from MainActivity or from somewhere?

Comment: are you sure when changing the activity you are not finishing `MainActivity` ?

Comment: @Raghvendra No main activity has not started

Comment: @Mahesh yes that is set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I end up doing (In case someone finds it helpful)

```
  @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you specify `android:parentActivityName` attribute and `<meta-data.../>` as below:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.EditProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_profile"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.ProfileActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.via.android.activity.ProfileActivity" />
    </activity>
```

You simply have to set 
       `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` in your `onCreate()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ...
}
```

and rest of the thing is handled by Android Framework.

**Remove** the below from your code:

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```